# Make subdomain files only accessible via subdomain

Tags: subdomain, file-permissions, directory

On a shared hosting I have a `public_html` directory where the site is located. There are multiple subdomains created and they are located in the `public_html` like `public_html/subdomain1`, `public_html/subdomain2` etc.

This makes these sub sites accessible in two ways:

1.) `domain.com/subdomain1`

2.) `subdomain.domain.com`

What I need is to forbid the first option for every subdomain.

Comment: have you tried htaccess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19118482/2774776

Comment: Thank you @JacobEvans, but that would deny the access to the subdomain in both cases. However, I need the case no 2, to be accessible.

Comment: no, only put the htaccess file in public html  to reference the subfolder

Comment: Best solution is to arrange all domains so that their root directories are in separate places. For example, `public_html/domain1`, `public_html/domain2` etc?

Answer (score 1):

This was the first question I stumbled upon while looking for this, and unfortunately it didn't get answered in over 5 years. So I figured it out and would like to share my approach here.

Using an `<If>` statemente (available from Apache 2.4 onwards), here's what you can do:

Put the following in an `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'mysubdomain.mydomain.tld'">
    Deny from all
</If>
```

If you need more control, e.g. to allow access for multiple (sub)domains, you can also you use RegEx:

```
<If "! %{HTTP_HOST} =~ m#^mysubdomain\.mydomain\.tld$#">
    Deny from all
</If>
```